# Override django model save function that extends AbstractBaseUser

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, authentication, django-rest-framework

Im using restframework for user signup
i need generate random password before save, i override save method in model but this never run and throw message password field is required.
¿How i can override this? Thanks.

```
# ViewSet.
class AgentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Agents.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AgentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['post']

# Model.
class Agents(AbstractBaseUser):
    oldkey = models.CharField(max_length=32, blank=True, null=True)
    is_main_user = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=45, blank=True, null=True)
    email1 = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, blank=True, null=True, unique=True
    )
    email2 = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey(
        'bdetail.Countries', models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='country',
        blank=True, null=True
    )
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=80, blank=True, null=True)
    num_access = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone1 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    phone2 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    phone3 = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    whatsapp = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
    permissions = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, blank=True, null=True, default='limited')
    fb_profile_id = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
    fb_access_token = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    clients = models.ForeignKey(
        'Clients', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True
    )
    last_login_time = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    about = models.TextField('Acerca de mi', blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email1'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['name']
    objects = MyUserManager()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'agents'

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name, ' ', self.lastname

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        raise Exception('ingres')

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.name) or u''

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add or update in your code

AgentSerializer(serializers.py)

```
class AgentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Agents

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return Agents.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

In views.py

```
class AgentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Agents.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AgentSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    http_method_names = ['post']

    def create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            Agents.objects.create_user(**serializer.validated_data)

            return Response(serializer.validated_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

        return JSONResponse(serializer.errors, status=400)
```

In models.py:

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def _create_user(self, email, password,
                 is_staff, **extra_fields):
        password= # Generate random password
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email,
        is_staff=is_staff, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        return self._create_user(email, password, False
                             **extra_fields)
```

Comment: The key is override create method in AgentViewSet thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try overriding the `create_user` method in your `MyUserManager`. Something like:

```
def create_user(self, **kwargs):
    kwargs['password'] = # Generate random password
    return super().create_user(**kwargs)
```

Comment: This doesn't work because, create_user never is called by restframework

Comment: This is odd since I have a project that uses RF and I did exactly this. Did you implement a custom sign up view/method?